# Invocation of a String Extension Method on a String vs Passing the String as a Parameter

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods, cil

Given a Class Definition :

```
Public Static Class Foo
{
    public static void Bar(this string A, string B, string C)
    {

    }
}
```

What would be the difference between passing the String Explicitly and Implicitly. Viz.

```
Foo instanceOfFoo="some value";
$(instanceOfFoo).Bar("b","c");
```

vs

```
Foo.Bar("a","b","c");
```

To clarify basis comments, the project I am working on implements a **String Extension Logger**, which according to my understanding seems a bad choice given that there are a million records of online orders with a lot of columns as varchar(even order_num is a varchar) that translate to strings.

However, since this is implemented by an architect, who seems to be convinced there would be no performance deterioration in using string extension methods, we are forced to use the String Extension method Logger.

I have taken the example as Foo and Bar, but in reality this is

**Logger 
.Info 
.Error** etc

Comment: There is no difference, extension methods are just syntactic sugar around your second block of code.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `$("Response-" + Response.Message.ToString())` to do though - that's not valid C#. It would really help if you'd provide a minimal valid example rather than pseudocode (note that `Public Static Class Log` won't compile either.)

Comment: That exension doesn't make much sense to me. You should not extend `String` but the logger or maybe `System.Object`(and determine the logger in the extension from the argument). You could call it like `this.LogInfo("message","AppArea","Region")`

Comment: You've really messed up the question now with your last edit. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Your code won't compile at all, and it's unclear what it's supposed to represent. It's not like an extension method costs memory for every string that lives in your application's memory, if that's what you're concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference other than the syntax, in fact the compiler will translate the implicit extension method call to the explicit call to a `static` method. Extension methods are just very sweet syntactic sugar.